# PyVista mesh triangulation - vertex indices

Tags: python, scipy, triangulation, delaunay, pyvista

I have a triangulated mesh that I generated with the Delaunay 3D function in PyVista. I would like to calculate the surface area of the mesh adding up the areas of all the triangles. Is there a way to obtain the indices of the simplices triangles from the delaunay result?

```
import pyvista as pv
cloud = pv.PolyData(points)
volume = cloud.delaunay_3d(alpha = 2.5)
shell = volume.extract_geometry()
shell.plot()
```

I know I can do it with Scipy but for whatever reason Scipy generates an incorrect mesh (and does not have attributes I can adjust in the Delaunay method):

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
tri = Delaunay(points)
print(tri.simplices)


[[386 466 377 613]
 [159 386 377 613]
 [159 386 466 613]
 ...
 [696 709 695 691]
 [696 710 711 691]
 [696 697 711 691]]
```

My goal is to loop through the triangles and calculate the surface area of the mesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyVista `PolyData` objects already have [an `area` property](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyData.area.html#pyvista.PolyData.area) that adds up the cell areas.

For example, consider random points on the unit sphere:

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

# random point cloud on a unit sphere
rng = np.random.default_rng()
N = 1000 # points
thetas = rng.random(N)*np.pi
phis = rng.random(N)*2*np.pi
points = np.array([
    np.sin(thetas)*np.cos(phis),
    np.sin(thetas)*np.sin(phis),
    np.cos(thetas),
]).T

# triangulate and compute total area
mesh = pv.PolyData(points)
triangulated = mesh.delaunay_3d().extract_surface()
print(triangulated.area, 4*np.pi)
```

For me this printed

```
12.47386243049973 12.566370614359172
```

The first value is the total area of our triangulated point cloud on a sphere, and the second value is the exact surface of a perfect unit sphere. Looks good.

Additionally, there are other similar attributes, for instance [`volume`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyData.volume.html) for watertight surfaces (which you have):

```py
>>> print(triangulated.volume, 4/3*np.pi)
4.127984347614561 4.1887902047863905
```

In other words, you don't need the vertex indices if you're only looking for the total area.

(If you *do* still want the vertices, the information is accessible via `triangulated.faces`. My recommendation would be to look at `triangulated.faces.reshape(-1, 4)[:, 1:]` which is a 2d array of shape `(n_cells, 3)`, where each row corresponds to a given triangle and the three integers in the row are the indices of the three points forming the corresponding triangle.)